# emacs configuration for android framework development

Tags: java, android, emacs, configuration, frameworks

I've been using emacs for writing c code.

But now i have to develop android framework which has c, cpp and java.

I've been satisfied with using gtags and cscope when dealing with c, but now it's different.

I found that gtags also provide code browsing for java. but when i try to make gtags (i.e., type 'gtags' in the root of android framework directory), it corrupts.

Is there any hero to share the emacs configuration for developing android framework? (gtags, cscope or any other..)

It would be helpful if someone shares the emacs init file(.emacs) file and extra jobs to work with android framework.

Thanks.

Comment: Might help? https://github.com/remvee/android-mode